# React setState not Updating Immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, setstate

I'm working on a todo application. This is a very simplified version of the offending code. I have a checkbox:

```
 <p><input type="checkbox"  name="area" checked={this.state.Pencil}   onChange={this.checkPencil}/> Writing Item </p>
```

Here's the function that calls the checkbox:

```
checkPencil(){
   this.setState({
      pencil:!this.state.pencil,
  }); 
  this.props.updateItem(this.state);
}
```

updateItem is a function that's mapped to dispatch to redux

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ updateItem}, dispatch);
}
```

My problem is that when I call the updateItem action and console.log the state, it is always 1 step behind. If the checkbox is unchecked and not true, I still get the state of true being passed to the updateItem function. Do I need to call another function to force the state to update?

Comment: Re-rendering is asynchronous to the `setState`. You may use the second `setState` argument that is invoked after the component is re-rendered. PS: it looks suspicious that you need to pass the complete component state upwards.

Comment: @zerkms I think I understand what you mean but could you elaborate on how I would call another setState in the context of a checkbox?

Comment: You don't call another `setState`. `setState` accepts a second argument that is a callback https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You should invoke your second function as a callback to setState, as setState happens asynchronously. Something like:

```
this.setState({pencil:!this.state.pencil}, myFunction)
```

However in your case since you want that function called with a parameter you're going to have to get a bit more creative, and perhaps create your own function that calls the function in the props:

```
myFunction = () => {
  this.props.updateItem(this.state)
}
```

Combine those together and it should work.

Comment: In arrow functions, `this` is bound to the enclosing scope, so I'm pretty sure you have that backwards.

Comment: The solution is not descriptive enough.

Comment: For functional components, at least on react 18, this does not work: `Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().`

Comment: What if I have a mapped state like const myFunction=()=>{
  Urls.map(url=>{
    setImagesUrl(prev=>[...prev,url])
  })
  console.log(imagesUrl) // I can't read it here
} . How am I gonna use my imagesUrl in the same function?

Answer (score 35):

Calling `setState()` in React is asynchronous, for various reasons (mainly performance). Under the covers React will batch multiple calls to `setState()` into a single state mutation, and then re-render the component a single time, rather than re-rendering for every state change.

Fortunately, the solution is rather simple - `setState` accepts a callback parameter:

```js
checkPencil: () => {
   this.setState(previousState => ({
      pencil: !previousState.pencil,
   }), () => {
      this.props.updateItem(this.state);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 32):

On Ben Hare's answer, If someone wants to achieve the same using React Hooks I have added sample code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

let [myArr, setMyArr] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4]) // the state on update of which we want to call some function

const someAction = () => {
  let arr = [...myArr]
  arr.push(5) // perform State update
  setMyArr(arr) // set new state
}

useEffect(() => { // this hook will get called every time myArr has changed
   // perform some action every time myArr is updated
   console.log('Updated State', myArr)
}, [myArr])
```

Answer (score 14):

When you're updating your state using a property of the current state, React documentation advise you to use the function call version of `setState` instead of the object.

So `setState((state, props) => {...})` instead of `setState(object)`.

The reason is that `setState` is more of a request for the state to change rather than an immediate change. React batches those `setState` calls for performance improvement.

Meaning the state property you're checking might not be stable.
This is a potential pitfall to be aware of.

For more info see documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

---

To answer your question, i'd do this.

```
checkPencil(){
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            pencil: !prevState.pencil
        };
    }, () => {
        this.props.updateItem(this.state)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It's because it happens **asynchronously**, so means in that time might not get updated yet...

According to React v.16 documentation, you need to use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object:

> #### State Updates May Be Asynchronous
>
> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> For example, this code may fail to update the counter:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function
>   rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state
>   as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied
>   as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Answer (score 7):

First set your value. after proceed your works.

```
this.setState({inputvalue: e.target.value}, function () {
    this._handleSubmit();
}); 

_handleSubmit() {
   console.log(this.state.inputvalue);
   //Do your action
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

I used both rossipedia's and Ben Hare's suggestions and did the following:

```
checkPencil(){
   this.setState({
      pencil:!this.state.pencil,
   }, this.updatingItem); 
}

updatingItem(){
    this.props.updateItem(this.state)
}
```

Comment: I got error this.props.updateItem is not a function.  I don't understand why this error occurring to in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Ben has a great answer for how to solve the immediate issue, however I would also advise to avoid duplicating state

If a state is in redux, your checkbox should be reading its own state from a prop or store instead of keeping track of the check state in both its own component and the global store

Do something like this:

```
<p>
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="area" checked={this.props.isChecked}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
    />
    Writing Item
</p>
```

The general rule is that if you find a state being needed in multiple places, hoist it up to a common parent (not always redux) to maintain only having a single source of truth

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
this.setState({inputvalue: e.target.value}, function () {
    console.log(this.state.inputvalue);
    this.showInputError(inputs[0].name);
});
```

showInputError function for validation if using any forms

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above `setState()` is asynchronous in nature. I solved this issue simply using `async` `await`.

Here's an example for refernce:

```
continue = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { values } = this.props;
        await this.setState({
            errors: {}
        });
        const emailValidationRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
        if(!emailValidationRegex.test(values.email)){
            await this.setState((state) => ({
                errors: {
                    ...state.errors,
                    email: "enter a valid email"
                }
            }));
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is React Hooks based solution.

Since React `useState` updates state asynchronously, check them in the `useEffect` hook if you need to see these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give the initialState in the useState each time using a variable. Like line 1 and 2. If I did not give anything in it it would work on double click to fill the errors variable.

```
  1) let errorsArray = [];
  2) let [errors, setErrors] = useState(errorsArray);
  3) let [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  4) let [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  let [gender, setGender] = useState('');
  let [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  let [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const performRegister = () => {
    console.log('firstName', isEmpty(firstName));
    if (isEmpty(firstName)) {
      console.log('first if statement');
      errorsArray.push({firstName: 'First Name Cannot be empty'});
    }
    if (isEmpty(lastName)) {
      errorsArray.push({lastName: 'Last Name Cannot be empty'});
    }
    if (isEmpty(gender)) {
      errorsArray.push({gender: 'Gender Cannot be empty'});
    }
    if (isEmpty(email)) {
      errorsArray.push({email: 'Email Cannot be empty'});
    }
    if (isEmpty(password)) {
      errorsArray.push({password: 'Password Cannot be empty'});
    }
    console.log('outside ERRORS array :::', errorsArray);
    setErrors(errorsArray);
    console.log('outside ERRORS :::', errors);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      console.log('ERROR exists');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also update the state twice like below and make the state update immediately, this worked for me:

```
this.setState(
        ({ app_id }) => ({
          app_id: 2
        }), () => {
          this.setState(({ app_id }) => ({
            app_id: 2
          }))
        } )
```