# Pass the data from the child to the parent using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `react js`. This might be an easy question but I am not getting a way to do this. So, I am asking this question.

I have a **grandParentComp** which is like

**GrandParent**

```
import React from 'react';

class QuizSetupMain extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            technologies: this.props.technologies,
            hasError: false
        }
    }
render() {
        return (

            <div >
            {this.state.technologies.length > 0 ? <LowLevelCriteria techData={this.state.technologies} /> : null}

    <div className="fetchBtnDiv mx-auto">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary fetchBtnSize" disabled={this.state.hasError}>Fetch Questions</button>
                </div>
</div>
```

Herem, I have button which I want to disable on the basis of the state variable

**LowCriteria.js** this is the child

import React from 'react';

```
class LowLevelCriteria extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            technologies: this.props.techData,
            lowData: this.props.lowData.low,
            hasError: false
        }
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.lowData.Low.length > 0) {
            console.log("in this");
            var previous_data = nextProps.lowData;
            var i = 0;
            previous_data.Low.map((object) => {
                i = i + parseInt(object.numberOfQuestions);
            });
            console.log("value of i is ==>", i);
            if (i >= 6) {
                this.setState({
                    hasError: true
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    hasError: false
                })
            }
        }
    }

  render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="questionLevelIndication">
                    <span className="levelIndicatorBtn backgroundColorForLow">
                        1
                    </span>
                    <label className="levelIndicationLabel">
                        Low Difficulty Level - Maximum 6 questions
                    </label>
                    {this.state.hasError && <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Please reduce number of questions</strong>
                    </div>}
                </div>
                {(this.props.lowData) && this.props.lowData.Low.length > 0 && this.props.lowData.Low.map(data => (
                    <LowRow technologies={this.state.technologies} hasError={this.state.hasError} onChange={this.onchange.bind(this)} data={data} key={data.id} onAddRow={this.onaddRow.bind(this)} onRemoveRow={this.onRemoveRow.bind(this)} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

So, Now I want to pass this `this.state.hasError` to the parent , so that I can disable the button which is on the parent component.

I dont want to use the redux.

Can any one help me with this ?

I don't have any button or function that is going to get called from the child function .so that I can update the parent state.

Comment: Do you mean `grandchild to parent`?  Or `grandchild to grandparent`? There's a difference

Comment: Sorry Actually from child to parent.

Comment: In my case from LowCriteria to the  GrandParent

Comment: There is no way to pass a state from a child to a parent in React.

Comment: Instead of passing down a value, you could instead pass down a function `setError` or something which is implemented in the grandparent component. The grandchild can then just call `this.props.setError(True)` or something when an error occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass state back to parent in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722382/how-to-pass-state-back-to-parent-in-react)

Comment: Okay , so Not using state or anything other than this ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Actually, I don't have any button or action that is going to get called from the child so that I can update the parent state. that's why I asked this

Comment: You didn't mention the React version, in recent versons you can use Context to connect component and stay decoupled. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) the documentation.

Comment: Just move your state up to the grandparent component and pass down a function that will modify the hasError value from your grandparent component to your child component

Comment: Your data is supposed to only flow down.  It's bad practice to move state upwards in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the parent's state directly from the child component. Your best bet would be to create a handler function that's passed down to the child that lives on the parent that updates the parent's state.

Comment: But I dont't have any function in the child which is going to get called on the change of that data.

Comment: Try moving the button to the child component. Then pass a function from the parent called `handleFetchQuestions` or something that deals with any API call (assuming from the name) that then updates the parent's state (`technologies`) based on the result. Technologies is being passed to the child anyways, so once you handle the fetching of questions in the parent and set its' new state, it will be passed to the child again. Then, you can deal with the error state directly within the child component and don't have to worry about passing anything up to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback function to handle this. Do as suggested below

In your GrandParent component declare handler function inside the component and set the flag to hasError. This flag is a Boolean which you will receive from a callback function from child component

```
 handleHasError = flag => {
      this.setState({
          hasError: flag
      });
 }
```

Pass down handleHasError to  LowLevelCriteria like

```
     {this.state.technologies.length > 0 ? <LowLevelCriteria techData={this.state.technologies} handleHasError={this.handleHasError}/> : null}
```

In your LowLevelCriteria component call this.props.handleHasError function like below

```
  if (i == 6) {
            this.setState({
                hasError: true
            })
           this.props.handleHasError(true);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                hasError: false
            })
          this.props.handleHasError(false);
        }
```

With this change the button will work as you expected

Edit:

You getMaximum update depth exceeded  because you are not comparing current props with nextProps. You are directly doing setState so you need to Compare them and then do setState

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(nextProps.lowData != this.props.lowData){
    if (nextProps.lowData.Low.length > 0) {
        console.log("in this");
        var previous_data = nextProps.lowData;
        var i = 0;
        previous_data.Low.map((object) => {
            i = i + parseInt(object.numberOfQuestions);
        });
        console.log("value of i is ==>", i);
        if (i == 6) {
            this.setState({
                hasError: true
            })
        this.props.handleHasError(true);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                hasError: false
            })
        this.props.handleHasError(false);
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Please excuse me if there are any typo errors because I am answering in my mobile

Comment: I did the same thing exact . But now it is giving me an error which is like ->

Comment: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: It might be because I am calling it in the componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)

Comment: Actually, now its not going in the condition So not getting called.

Comment: Both are same there is no change .So its not going inside that condition

Comment: And this data is going to be same everytime.

Comment: becaue willReceiveProps alway gives the updated data so.

Comment: No. Hold on I updated componentWillReceiveProps code give a try now

Comment: Here, where should I call that handler method ?

Comment: I added in the answer already if you read my answer well you will understand

Comment: Yes I got this one. But now then  when I call this and send this.state.haserror as a param then it is receiving alwsy false.

Comment: The following condition never becomes true if (i >= 6) {. You need to know when you need to send true to that function.

Comment: I am really sorry, I actually have not looked the condition properly. Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain how you resolved that issue ? a bit explaionation.

Comment: What I want to do is that if i is equal to 6 then I need to enable that button but if  its is greater or less than 6 then it should disable that button.

Comment: And it is because , I think state is not getting updated immdieatly so it is setting it as a false every time.

Comment: That’s simply logic. You must have tried on your own. I updated my answer please give a try. To make hasError to true you make sure you get i value 6. Only then hasError will turn to true otherwise it will be false always

Comment: Yes That is done. Your answer is working fine. But only thing is that while sending state value its no sending the latest value.

Comment: Just take the componentWillReceiveProps code from my answer and give a try now. I just updated the code

Comment: @ganeshkaspate do upvote and accept any of the answers provide  which resolves your issue. So that the thread it will help future readers