# Pass props to another component onclick of a button

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In my nextJS app, I want to pass props of one component to another which is neither a parent nor child of first component.How can I do that?

There is a `Order` component inside a div in `Orders` page and `OrderViewer` in another div.What I want is that when I click the 'View Order' button,`orderno` of that order should pass to `OrderViewer` component.

orders.js

```
<div>
   <div><Order 
     orderno='abc'
 title='abc'
 status='abc'
 entity='abc'
 po='abc'
 duedate='abc' /></div>
</div>
<div><OrderViewer /></div>
```

Order.js

```
<div>
<button>View Order</button>
    <p><span>{this.props.orderno}</span> 
    <span>{this.props.title}</span></p>
    <p>{this.props.entity} - {this.props.po}</p>
    <p>Due {this.props.duedate}</p>
</div>
```

OrderViewer.js

```
<div>//should display the orderno of clicked `order`</div>
```

Once `orderno` passed,`Orderviewer` displays it.I saw so many this kind of 'passing props' questions here but none of them had this kind of situation.Any tip is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to deal with callbacks. Callback is a concept in react.

Declare an event handler function in orders.js which sets the orderId to the state when button  clicked in orders.js component and pass down that event handler function to Order component as props and pass down orderId as a prop to OrderViewer component

orders.js

```
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
           orderId: null
      }
  }
  handleViewOrder = orderId = {
      this.setState({
          orderId
      });
  }
  render(){
    return(<div>
     <div><Order 
       orderno='abc'
       title='abc'
      status='abc'
      entity='abc'
      po='abc'
      duedate='abc' handleViewOrder={this.handleViewOrder} /></div>
  </div>
  <div><OrderViewer orderId={this.state.orderId} /></div>)}
```

Now in order.js access the received handler function using props and assign it to button onClick by passing orderId

```
   <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.handleViewOrder(this.props.orderno)}>View Order</button>
      <p><span>{this.props.orderno}</span> 
     <span>{this.props.title}</span></p>
     <p>{this.props.entity} - {this.props.po}</p>
     <p>Due {this.props.duedate}</p>
 </div>
```

Now, you can access orderId using this.props.orderId in OrderViewer component and display it

OrderViewer.js

```
   <div>{this.props.orderId}</div>
```

So having an event handler function in parent component and passing down as props to child component and assigning to child component button onClick and when clicked changing parent state is so called callbacks in react. If you understand what I am trying to explain in my answer you can get going easily

Edit:

In Order.js component

Change

```
  <button onClick={() => this.handleViewOrder(this.props.orderno)}>View Order</button>
```

To

```
   <button onClick={() => this.props.handleViewOrder(this.props.orderno)}>View Order</button>
```

Also you are calling Order component in loop but you are not setting unique key to Order component so

Change

```
            { Orders.map((order) => <Order 
                 orderno={order.orderno}
            title={order.title}
                 status={order.status}
                entity={order.entity}
                po={order.po}
            duedate={order.duedate}
            handleViewOrder={this.handleViewOrder}/> )}
```

To

```
            { Orders.map((order) => <Order 
            orderno={order.orderno}
            title={order.title}
            status={order.status}
                entity={order.entity}
            po={order.po}
                            key={order.orderno}
            duedate={order.duedate}
            handleViewOrder={this.handleViewOrder}/> )}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, reasoning is:

1. you have some parent component/screen. Lets call it `OrdersPage`
2. within `OrdersPage` you have 2 components: `Order` and `OrdersViewer`
3. what you are interested in, within context of parent components (`OrdersPage`) is to know which order was clicked and show that in other child
4. obviously, you need `state` on your `OrdersPage` component
5. when you click some order, you will put it in state
6. your other component will receive `state` as `props` and show clicked component