# sending data to parent component when a random div is clicked in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm creating an N number of `div`s using an array of objects named 'allContacts' and map function. When one of these `div`s is clicked, I want to send the respective div id to the parent component. How can I do that? Each div has different id and here id refers to `eachContact.ID`.

I'm not able to use props to send the data as it is showing 'undefined'.  Can I use `Link` in react-router to send data (I'm using React Router)?

```
displayEachContact() {
        addressBookUIFunctionality.prototype.hideAddPopup();
        return (
            this.props.AllContacts.map(function (eachContact) {
                return (
                    <Link to={'/'+eachContact.ID} style={{textDecoration:         'none'}} >
                    {/* onClick={() =>     AllContacts.prototype.displayContact(eachContact)} */}
                    <div id={eachContact.ID} className="each_contact inactive_contact">
                        <span className="contact_summary contact_summary_first_field">{eachContact.Name}</span>
                        <span className="contact_summary">{eachContact.Email}</span>
                        <span className="contact_summary">{eachContact.Mobile}</span>
                    </div>
                    </Link>
                );

            })
            )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Route exact path='/allContacts'>
                <div className="contacts">
                    {this.displayEachContact()}
                </div>
            </Route>
        );
    }
```

Comment: You can define a function in the parent component and pass it as a prop to child component. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264486/pass-props-to-another-component-onclick-of-a-button

Comment: Lets suppose i have a function from parent called getContactId which i sent to this chid component. Tell me how to send the data back to parent when i click that specific div.

Answer (score 0):

```
displayEachContact() {
    addressBookUIFunctionality.prototype.hideAddPopup();
    return (
        this.props.AllContacts.map(function (eachContact) {
            return (
                <Link to={'/'+eachContact.ID} style={{textDecoration:'none'}} >
                { onClick={() =>  this.props.displayContact(eachContact.ID)}}
                <div id={eachContact.ID} className="each_contact inactive_contact">
                    <span className="contact_summary contact_summary_first_field"> 
                      {eachContact.Name}</span>
                    <span className="contact_summary">{eachContact.Email}</span>
                    <span className="contact_summary">{eachContact.Mobile}</span>
                </div>
                </Link>
            );

        })
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Route exact path='/allContacts'>
                <div className="contacts">
                    {this.displayEachContact()}
                </div>
            </Route>
        );
```

On click of div call one function like `this.props.displayContact(eachContact.ID)` from parent component and pass ID or whatever you want as parameter.

Comment: hello prakash! i've tried this method but facing an issue with this keyword. It says this implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation

Comment: @xandercage can you please add your complete class component code, so that i can tell you whats wrong.