# how to pass state from child component to parent component in reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {       
       render(){
        return(   
        //IN HERE I'm calling child parent    
          <ChildComponent/>
        )
        }        
        }

class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          sample: '',        
        };  
    }
```

how can I get the sample state to the parent component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722382/how-to-pass-state-back-to-parent-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. So at the Parent Component make a method which receives value in return.

   ```
   StateValue = (value) =>{
    console.log(value);
   }
   ```
2. Pass this method as props to the child component.

   ```
   <ChildComponent method={this.StateValue}/>
   ```
3. At the child component Pass the state value to the method props received in step 2.

   ```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sample: 'hi',        
    };  
    }

    render(){
      this.props.method(this.state.sample)

      return(
        <></>
      )
   ```

You will get your state value in StateValue Method from the props in your parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          sample: '',        
        };  
    }

      render(){
        return(   
          <ChildComponent sample={this.state.sample} setState={(sample) => this.setState({ sample })} />
          )
         }        
        }

class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {    
// you can now call this.props.setState(value); to set parent component state.
// and access the sample state: this.props.sample;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to specify a callback as a prop. Like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
      onSample = (sample) => {
          // handle sample
       }

       render(){
        return(   
        //IN HERE I'm calling child parent    
          <ChildComponent
            callback={this.onSample}
          />
        )
        }        
      }

class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          sample: '',        
        };
        this.onSample = props.callback
        // call later on via this.onSample(<sample>);
    }
```