# How to pass props to parent from child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to create a "CV-Generator" like this [like this](https://michalosman.github.io/cv-application/), What happens here is whenever user puts a value in any of the input it automatically renders to the Render preview(right side),
My problem here is I am rendering a `<Form />` where it renders three child components namely:-
`<PersonalInfo />`, `<Experience />`, `<Education />`, In each of three I process Input onChange and `setState` the data, but problem is I need to render this data to again Render Preview(right on the link), But I am confused how can I pass my data from child components(i.e. `<PersonalInfo />`, `<Experience />`, `<Education />`) to the parent Component(`<App />`)

*App.js*

```
return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Form />           //need data from her childs
      <DisplayInfo />    //want to pass data to this one
    </div>
  );
```

*Form.js*

```
return (
      <form>
        <PersonalInfo /> //need data from here
        <Experience />   //need data from here
        <Education />    //need data from here
      </form>
    );
```

*Example `state` from one of the three child*

```
this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      title: '',
      address: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      email: '',
      description: '',
    };
// want to pass all this data
```

Comment: See [Components and Props
](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#overview](Components and Props)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass state back to parent in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722382/how-to-pass-state-back-to-parent-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this for **Form** component

```
   return (
  <form>
   <PersonalInfo 
      firstName: {firstName},
      lastName: {lastName},
      title: {title},
      address: {address},
      phoneNumber: {phoneNumber},
      email: {email},
      description: {description},
   /> 
   <Experience />   
   <Education />    
 </form>
);
```

And do this for the **DisplayInfo.js**

```
    function DisplayInfo({firstName,lastName,title,address,phoneNumber,email,address}) {
      return (
        <div className='container'>
           //your code here for example
           <h1>First Name:-{firstname}</h1>
            <p>Description:-{description}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callback in child, and then some function in parent to get those data. But remember that you have to trigger the callback function first.