# Date component passing the value to parent component react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, use-state

I want to create a date component on a child component and show on the screen (on the parent component) the selected date. Moreover I have two problems:

- I am not managing to make the components talk with each other. I can print on the console the answer from the child component but I cannot pass to the parent component
- When I select date "custom" on my dropdown I want to select a start and end date but I can't do it, when I select one of the dates (start or the end) the other updates itself automatically.

Any help is welcome :)

Here is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-forked-h1u9s?file=/src/App.tsx

This is how I call the date component

```
  export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DateComponent />
      <div>Your chosen date was: </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the date component:

```
return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <ReactSelect
            value={selectedOption as ValueType<OptionType>}
            onChange={(option) => handleChange(option)}
            isMulti={false}
            options={options}
          />

          {selectedOption === DateValueEnum.Custom ? (
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              <div style={{ width: "50%", float: "left", paddingRight: "5px" }}>
                <DatePicker
                  fullWidth
                  margin="normal"
                  required={true}
                  error={false}
                  invalidLabel={"Several values..."}
                  value={selectedDate}
                  onChange={(newDate) => setSelectedDate(newDate)}
                  format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                />
              </div>
              <DatePicker
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
                required={true}
                error={false}
                invalidLabel={"Several values..."}
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={(newDate) => setSelectedDate(newDate)}
                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
              />
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: in react components dont "talk to each other"..... you need to create a redux store, reducer and useSelector

Comment: Components communicate via stores, context API, and passing event handlers to children (e.g. `onDateSelected`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722382/how-to-pass-state-back-to-parent-in-react (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share state or function between components.
There is many ways to do it

You can share state directly from Parent component to children, before sharing state you need to create one with React useState hook

like so:

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState("")
 
<DateComponent setDate={setDate} />
```

Here we passed the `setDate` function to the children component.
When we will call that function in  `DateComponent` we will change the Parrent component's state

```
 props.setDate("date")
```

read about state and life cycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), it will help you a lot.
Also read about [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), which were used previosly.

Another way to pass data between components is [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)  it's more complicated way, or you can use library like Redux, Mobx.

About "custom" selected option, you created  only one state for two options, so when you pick the date, both are changed. To fix it you nedd to add second state.

here the fixed version: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-forked-lkk1k?file=/src/App.tsx:723-759)

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was super helpful! I am having a look on useContext on the docs to learn more about it :)

Comment: ps: I realized that my dropdown do not show the chosen option after I click. I am investigating but if you have any input on this I will happily accept too ^^

Comment: In your options array, you need rename "key" to "value", and when you handleSelect , you should pass all option, not option.key

Comment: Thank you a million Yaroslav! I got it working now :)

Comment: you are welcome :)