# React - How to get state objects from nested components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting developing form in React and I've made every field of form a separate component. So, from picture below:
Component A - is form with submit function
Component B - is file input (for example)

How to fetch state objects of nested components after clicking Submit button? I know that I can pass function to nested components witch will update parent state but maybe there is better solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you atleat show some of your snippet code for better observation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass state back to parent in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722382/how-to-pass-state-back-to-parent-in-react)

Comment: You can use a state manager like Redux or Jotai. Or you can passe a setState as props et get all data directly in component A.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, because I don't want to pass the data to parent every time when child is changing. I want do it other way: get data when button is clicked. Maybe the result is the same but in child component I'm doing operation on files (adding, deleting, changing) and I don't want every time to pass them to parent

Answer (score 0):

```
`Component A 
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  export default function componentA(){
  const [componentA, setcomponentA] = useState("A Component")
   return(
         <>
          <div>
            <ComponentB Data = {componentA} />
          </div>
         </>
       )
  }
Component B 
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function componentB({Data}){
return(
      <>
        <div>
          <h1>{Data}</h1>
        </div>
     </>
   )
 }`
```

Comment: In React, you can pass state from parent components to nested (child) components as props. This allows you to share data and state information between different parts of your application.

Comment: Define State in Parent Component:
Start by defining the state in the parent component. This state can include any data or variables that you want to share with the child component.
Pass State as a Prop:
Inside the parent component's render method, pass the state variable as a prop to the child component. In this example, we're passing parentState to ChildComponent as the state prop.

Comment: Access State in Child Component:
In the child component, you can access the state using the prop that was passed. You can use it just like any other prop.

Comment: Now, the ChildComponent has access to the state from the ParentComponent. If the state in the parent component changes, the child component will re-render with the updated state.

This is how you can pass state from a parent component to a nested child component in React. It's a fundamental concept for managing and sharing data within your application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In React, you have several options for managing and collecting state from nested components when a form is submitted. Here are some common approaches

```
// Component A (parent)
function FormComponent() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({/* initial form data */});
  
  const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    // Access formData and submit the form
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentB formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
      {/* Other form fields */}
      <button onClick={handleFormSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Component B (child)
function ComponentB({ formData, setFormData }) {
  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    // Update formData with the file data
    setFormData({ ...formData, file: event.target.files[0] });
  }

  return (
    <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
  );
}
```

Comment: This looks good! I'll try to do it that way :)