# Why ReactJS state cannot be accessed in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling the data from `MongoDB` database using `axios` and set the value to a `state` value named **invoices**

I do this in `componentDidMount`. And again I want to access that state (i.e. invoices) within the `componentDidMount`. I am trying to set `invoices` value to another `state` value called `dataa`. But always ends up getting empty/null.

**Problem is the state has Not been set, value is empty**

This is what my code snippet looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {

axios
  .get("http://localhost:4005/purchaseinvoices")
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      invoices: response.data //setting value to invoices
    });
  })
  .then(
    this.setState({
      dataa: this.state.invoices //setting value to dataa
    })
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  //but this gives 0
  alert(this.state.invoices.length)

}
```

what is the possible cause of problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `axios` and `setState` are asynchronous.

But, you can see updated stated in `componentDidUpdate` or in `render` function.

**Edit**: Also you can access just the stated is updated like below;

```
axios
  .get("http://localhost:4005/purchaseinvoices")
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      invoices: response.data, //setting value to invoices
      dataa: response.data
    }, () => {
      alert(this.state.invoices.length)
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I need to see the changes when the page loads. I am using that `data` state value on a component. So I need to see the changes  when the component mounted. How can I do this?

Comment: Thank you for this approach. And the other problem is I need to update `dataa` state value too.  for this. I have some pre-configured data object. I need to add what I get from `invoices` to that. I am doing that(concatation) in the callback function and try to to `setState({dataa: this.state.invoices})` it gives me this error **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Comment: @BhagyaKolithaJayalath You can updated `dataa` as updating `invoices`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Honestly this is what I am trying to do. When I do this, I get this error I mentioned in the above comment. This is what I am trying to do `axios
      .get("http://localhost:4005/purchaseinvoices")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ invoices: response.data }, () => {
          TableValues.rows = this.state.invoices
          this.setState({
            dataa: TableValues
          })
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });`

Comment: It seems like there's a problem in using state values. It can be better to provide more detail information about that in your question. Then I can help you.

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you? maybe chat?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to use chat box :(

Comment: @BhagyaKolithaJayalath Then please add information as comment. :)

Comment: I should provide the full snippet then only you can understand. Otherwise it cannot be explain easily and understandably

Answer (score 0):

Update the data directly from response instead of using this.state.invoices.since this.setState is an async call,takes some ms delay to update the state.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4005/purchaseinvoices")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          invoices: response.data //setting value to invoices
          data: response.data
        });

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });


    }
```

If you want to see the data on first load of page ,try server side rendering