# Why does setState not change state inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

What is the reason for isTrue not changing to true? As you can see I am setting it inside the useEffect. What exactly is happening here?

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsTrue(true)
    console.log(isTrue) //still gives me false
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

You have a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `isTrue === false` value, you can have another `useEffect` which listens to its changes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsTrue(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isTrue);
  }, [isTrue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```