# Unable to update state on axios response in a class react js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm unable to update the state using the axios response in a class component. It works just fine with function based components. Could somebody please point out what is causing this issue. I'm new to react and tried most of the possible answers out there.

code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Table.css";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import Example from "./Progress";

class Tables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      submitted: false,
      task_id: "",
    };
    this.handlesubmit = this.handlesubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handlesubmit(event) {
    var self = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/",
      data: {
        project_name: "test",
      },
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.task_id); //prints taskid (12345678)
      self.setState({
        task_id: response.data.task_id,
      });
      console.log(self.task_id); //prints undefined
    });
    this.setState({ submitted: true }); //works fine, state is set to true
    console.log(this.task_id); //prints undefined
  }

  render() {
    let modal;
    let task_id = this.state.task_id;
    let submitted = this.state.submitted;
     if (submitted === true) {
     modal = <Example pro="test" task={task_id} />;
      }

    return (
      <div className="table-div">
        <Button
          buttonStyle="btn--secondary"
          buttonSize="btn--small--opt"
          onClick={this.handlesubmit}
        >
          test
        </Button>
        {modal}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tables;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous and it will update `task_id` on the next render. Also, `setState` takes a callback - `this.setState({}, () => { console.log(this.task_id) })` that you can use if you need access the updated state after you call `setState`.

Comment: @goto1, actually after the response is received, i need to send it to another component. since it is showing undefined it throws an error. tbh, this is my first time with react and i'm not understanding most of the parts. If you could show where to add this callback, it would be a great help

Comment: How are you "sending it to another component?"

Comment: that part i hadn't added to the code here. now updated, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `state` inside `then` when the `axios` call succeeds:

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  axios({...})
    .then((response) => { 
      this.setState({
        task_id: response.data.task_id,
        submitted: true
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { /* handle errors appropriately */ })
}
```

Then, inside your `render` method, make sure that both `task_id` and `submitted` have appropriate values before rendering the `modal`:

```
render() {
  const { task_id, submitted } = this.state
  const modal = submitted && task_id !== ""
    ? <Example pro="test" task={task_id} />
    : null // don't render anything

  return (
    <div className="table-id">
      <Button ...>test</Button>
      {modal}
    </div>
  )
}
```