# Destructuring need waitFor

Tags: destructuring, react-hooks-testing-library

Why does destructuring need waitFor?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-glitter-9ixgx?file=/src/resolved.test.ts)

All tests do the same thing. In the **'ok.test.ts'** file I use renderHook, I use `result.current[1]`  to set the state and `result.current[0]` to get the value of the state, so far so good.

In **'not-ok'** tests I do destructuring the result of renderHook and the tests fail because the state value is incorrect.

In **'resolved.test.ts'** when using waitFor the test with destructuring works. I understand that set states is async. I didn't understand why the **'ok.test.ts'** works without waitFor and without destructuring, but if I do destructuring I need waitFor.

Comment: You need to use `waitFor` because setting state (calling `set` in your case) is an async operation. See [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately) for details.

Comment: @juliomalves I edited the question to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of `react-hooks-testing-library` here.

TL;DR; you cant destructure `result.current` and have `get` receive updated values.

This comes up a lot so I'll take some time to give a more detailed answer for anyone coming across this.

Firstly, in your example, the `resolved` test is passing because `waitFor` returns a promise that your must `await` to see the failure:

```
// ...
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(get).toStrictEqual({
        data1: 1,
        data2: 2,
        data3: 3
      });
    });
// ...
```

In this case, it times out waiting for the expectation pass because the value never changes.

So the real question is why isn't `get` (odd name BTW... `state` would be more appropriate in this example) updating when `set` is called?

Well, let's look at this code:

```
const result = {
  state: 0,
  setState(newState: number) {
    this.state = newState;
  }
};

const { state, setState } = result;

setState(1);

expect(state).toBe(1); // fails
```

The test fails for the same reason as your examples. Can you see why?

Well, The destructuring of `result` *locks* the value of `result.state` to whatever it was at that moment in a new variable called `state`.  Calling `setState` (or `result.setState`) will successfully update `result.state`, but there is no link to the `state` variable so the value does not change.

So by having `const { result: { current: [get, set] } } = renderHook(...)` you are also locking `get` to whatever the initial value of `result.current` has and not amount of `set`ting is going to allow the new variable to be updated because it's connection to `result.current` has been lost.

Finally, I see this as a common accident, especially when using tuple results from hooks (e.g. `const [state, setState] = useState()`).  The common reason given is that people don't like referring to them as `result.current[0]` and `result.current[1]` in their tests.  I can sympathise with that.

Another thing many people don't realise is that the value of `result.current` is whatever you return from the `renderHook` callback so you can easily get nicely named value by changing your `renderHook` call to something like:

```
// ...
    const { result } = renderHook(() => {
      const [get, set] = React.useState({
        data1: 0,
        data2: 0,
        data3: 0
      })
      return { get, set }
    });

    act(() => {
      result.current.set({ data1: 1, data2: 2, data3: 3 });
    });

    expect(result.current.get).toStrictEqual({
      data1: 1,
      data2: 2,
      data3: 3
    });
  });
// ...
```

Anyway, hope that clears it up and happy testing!

Comment: That was a fantastic answer, it's very clear now.  Thank you. PS really `get` is a bad name, I see it now.