# Delay in the state change

Tags: reactjs, use-state

When I press "Submit" button the console shows "success" even though the input is empty, and when I press again it finally shows "error".

How do I change the code so that console will show "error" when I press the button for the first time?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input === "") {
      setError(true);
    }
    if (error) {
      console.log("error");
      return;
    }
    console.log("success");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look again at the state declaration:

```js
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
```

There is no way that calling `setError` is going to change `error`, because it's a `const`. The language doesn't allow it.

What happens is that the `useState` hook will return the value passed to `setError` *the next time the component renders*.

If you adjust your `handleSubmit` logic a bit, accounting for the fact that it knows when it calls `setError(true)`, you can achieve the desired result:

```js
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input === "") {
      setError(true);
      console.log("error");
      return;
    }
    console.log("success");
  };
```

All I did was remove two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state in React is an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, like in your example, the `console.log` function runs before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.
Like so:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   // Actions we want to happen when the state has been fully updated.
}, [state]);
```

For your example, it can look like this:

```js
const submitHandler = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (input === "") {
     setError(true);
   }
}

useEffect(() => {
   // No need for === true
   if (error) {
     console.log("error");
     return;
   }
   console.log("success");
}, [error])
```

Answer (score 0):

[State change is async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately), you should check first submit against another state or a reference (`useRef`).

```
function App() {
  const [isFirstSubmit, setIsFirstSubmit] = useState(true);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (isFirstSubmit) {
      console.log("error");
      setIsFirstSubmit(false);
    }
  };
  return <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>...</form>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code to

```
if (input === "") {
  setError(true);
  console.log("error");
  return;
}

console.log("success");
```

So in first **if** you can handle error condition where after it will be success.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the asynchronous mechanism of the set state. It's all about closures. In the handler function, the value of `error` will equal its value during the last render (at the time when this function was actually created).

What `setError(true)` does is that it schedules a component re-render with the new value of `error`. The value of `error` will be `true` during the next render after `setError` was called.

Assuming that you just want to see a relevant message upon submit, you don't need the error state at all.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input === "" ? "error" : "success")
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```