# React - Input value not assigned if submit button is pressed directly

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, submit

Given the following code:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("telFormValues when submit:"+JSON.stringify(telFormValues));
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      "telefonos_empresa": telFormValues,
      "emails_empresa": emailFormValues
    });
```

Which is part of a form using TextFields with onChange, when text is placed in a input and I click the submit button directly,(handleSubmit is called) the console.log for `telFormValues` shows the data from the form correctly, however, `formValues` does not register the last input, unless I click out of it. It happens with any input in the form if it is the last one, if the user clicks submit directly, is not 'saved'. I don't understand why is this behaviour happening and after all, the console shows that the value is indeed there, but for some reason it is not setting on `setFormValues`.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(formValues["telefonos_empresa"]))` shows: `[{"tel_identificator":"test1","tel":"234"}]`

`console.log(formValues)` (placed right in the following line) shows: `telefonos_empresa: []`

Edit: Per suggestion, tried:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("telFormValues en submit:"+JSON.stringify(telFormValues));
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      "telefonos_empresa": telFormValues,
      "emails_empresa": emailFormValues
    }, 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formValues["telefonos_empresa"])),
        console.log(formValues)
      );
  };
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: @NickVu could you check it please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately this should help

Comment: @ElPandario if I'm not wrong, they say in this link that setState() in React is asynchronous, so I put the console.log inside a setTimeOut to 3 seconds and still the same result.

Comment: Have you tried to make the function async and use await?

Comment: I mean, I don't think I have something abnormal in my code. Does every form in react need to manipulate a simple submit function? I don't think this is the premise to solve it.

Comment: What I usually do to counter this problem, is that I make an handleChange (which basically update the state) function on my inputs. That way when I submit my form all states are updated.