# How do I set a let variable to a const that uses useState? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

This is what I'm trying to do inside the export default function

```
   const Create = () => {
  handleClose();
  let temp = '';
  if (thing1) {
    temp= 'text';
  }
  if (thing2) {
    temp += 'text';
  }
  if (thing3) {
    temp += 'text';
  }
  if (thing4) {
    temp += 'text';
  }
  if (thing5) {
    temp += 'text';
  }
  setsel(temp);
```

Obviously I have something else for temp, having it loop through things to get a value but that's the basic idea - It comes back as undefined when I console.log "thing" to test it out.

Comment: This should be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67681192/10004072 you need to wait for state to update

Answer (score 1):

Utilising the answer from stackoverflow.com/a/67681192/10004072 to suit your context

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const [thing, setthing] = useState(''); // the state on update of which we want to call some function

const someAction = () => {
  let temp = 'test';
  setthing(temp); // the state will now be 'test'
}

useEffect(() => { // this hook will get called every time when thing has changed
   console.log('Updated State', thing)
}, [thing])
```

Comment: I added the full code i used, obv. different variable names - Would I need the useEffect thing?

Comment: Yes, that's the callback. Without it, your console.log runs before state has even had a chance to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete and lacks information. What exactly do you want to do?

If you want to set a value to the initial thing state, put inside the use state what you want to put. Example:

```
const [thing, setthing] = useState(test);
```

why do you want to set the value of another variable to the thing state? why not set it directly?

Comment: As I mentioned but I probs wasn't specific, it doesn't show the full thing - Basically, I have conditionals for the temp, which happens after all the const declarations for useState and others (there are many others) - Thus, I need to set it after

Comment: I added more context

Answer (score 0):

Leslie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73188333/853837) looks correct to me

Here is what's going wrong with example you shared:

Referring to the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
> state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.

`setthing(temp)` is not going to change value of `thing` in this render, it is going to render with current value, and then re-render the component with `thing` set to `temp`. Which in the sample example you shared will result in infinite renders.

Comment: Hmm, ok - Would it just be the useEffect part that I'm missing?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. It is hard to figure out from your example.

Comment: I want to update the state variable "thing" to the value that is inside temp, which I use later on in the code