# localStorage resets to empty on refresh in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a shopping cart system in my next.js app using Context.

I define my cart with `useState`:

`const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);`

Then I use `useEffect` to check and update the localStorage:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))) {
      const storedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"));
      setCartItems([...cartItems, ...storedCartItems]);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  }, [cartItems]);
```

This stores the items in localStorage fine, but when I refresh, it resets the `cartItems` item in localStorage to an empty array. I've seen a few answers where you get the localStorage item before setting the cart state but that throws `localStorage is not defined` errors in Next. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setCartItems` sets the value of `cartItems` for the next render, so on the initial render it's `[]` during the second `useEffect`

You can fix this by storing a ref (which doesn't rerender on state change) for whether it's the first render or not.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// ...

// in component

const initialRender = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))) {
        const storedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"));
        setCartItems([...cartItems, ...storedCartItems]);
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (initialRender.current) {
        initialRender.current = false;
        return;
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}, [cartItems]);
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I haven't seen that solution anywhere else, but I think a lot of similar problems have been with React rather than Next.

Comment: Yeah this (setting localhost to empty array) isn't an issue with Next, it's with React

Answer (score 1):

React never updates state immediately It's an asynchronous process, for example, if you console.log(stateValue) just after the setState() method you'll get prevState value in a log. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558319).

That is exactly happening here, you have called setState method inside the first useEffect, state has not updated yet by react and we're trying to update localStorage with the latest state value(for now it's [] since react has not updated the state yet). that's why the localStorage value holds an empty array.

For your case, you can skip the first execution of 2nd useEffect as @Samathingamajig's mentioned in his answer.

**PS:** Thanks @Samathingamajig for pointing out the silly mistake, I don't know how missed that. LOL

Comment: I don't think this will work properly though. On the initial render, `cartItems` will be `[]`. In the first `useEffect`, `cartItems` in localstorage will be set to the empty array. In the second `useEffect`, it will go inside the for loop because an empty array is truthy. The value of `storedCartItems` will be an empty array (because of the first `useEffect`) and the value of `cartItems` will still be an empty array, so the `setCartItems()` will keep `cartItems` as an empty array.