# What's wrong with my code? It returns an empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a project using React, TypeScript, and Unsplash API. Basically, I'm trying to create an app to search for images, but my code is returning an empty array. What's wrong with my code?

**ContextApi file**

```js
import axios from "axios"
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react"

interface Image {
    id: string
    urls: {
        regular: string
    }
}

interface SearchContextProps {
    searchImage: string
    setSearchImage: (searchImage: string) => void
    images: Image[]
    setImages: (images: Image[]) => void
    fetchData: (query?: string) => Promise<void>
}

export const ImageContext = createContext({} as SearchContextProps)

interface SearchContextProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode
}

function ImageSearchProvider({ children }: SearchContextProviderProps) {
    const [searchImage, setSearchImage] = useState("")
    const [images, setImages] = useState<Image[]>([])

    async function fetchData(query?: string) {
        const response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?per_page=30&query=${
                query || searchImage
            }&client_id=${import.meta.env.VITE_UNSPLASH_API_KEY}`
        )

        setImages(response.data.results)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <ImageContext.Provider
            value={{
                searchImage,
                setSearchImage,
                images,
                setImages,
                fetchData,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </ImageContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ImageSearchProvider
```

This is the Gallery component. The `console.log(images)` is returning an empty array and I don't know why.

```js
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ImageContext } from "../../contexts/ImageContext"
import { GalleryContainer, Img } from "./styles"

interface Image {
    id: string
    urls: {
        regular: string
    }
}

function Gallery() {
    const { images } = useContext(ImageContext)
    console.log(images)

    return (
        <GalleryContainer>
            {images.map((image: Image) => {
                return <Img key={image.id} src={image.urls.regular} />
            })}
        </GalleryContainer>
    )
}

export default Gallery
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Comment: Please see [ask] for tips on good question titles, then revise yours to be more specific.

Comment: is `response.data.results` from `fetchData` returning something?

Comment: Returns Array(0). In my other component (SearchComponent), where I have a form with input and a submit button, when I search for a photo, everything works and the photos appear in my Gallery container.