# Failed to invoke Async Functions (Api Calls) sequentially

Tags: react-native, api, async-await, axios

So I have to make two api calls in my app. The first one is a POST request that creates a new game model. The second one is a GET request that uses a value from the first request. I tried to write a function so that it could all be invoked sequentially. However it seems like it's not working properly :(

Function and used states

```
  const dateTime = new Date().toJSON();
  const [code, setNewCode] = useState("");
  const [gameData, setGameData] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
      try {
        const firstResponse = await axios
          .post(apiUrl + "/games", {
            game: {
              name: dateTime,
            },
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.code);
            setNewCode(response.data.code);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            console.log(code);
          });
        const thirdResponse = await axios
          .get(apiUrl + "/games/" + code)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
            setGameData(newData);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally();
        console.log("Get is done");
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    };
    asyncFunction();
  }, []);
```

And here is the log that I get in console:

```
LOG ST231 // code that is taken from json.response from POST request
LOG       // somehow empty value of code state that should've been updated by the POST request
LOG {"id":6,"name":"2023-02-28T12:55:01.221Z","code":"BX892","fight":false,"turn":0,"created_at":"2023-02-28T12:55:01.326Z","updated_at":"2023-02-28T12:55:01.326Z","user_id":1,"status":"active","players":[],"monsters":[]} // response from GET request. Why is the code "BX892"? Where did is take it? How is it possible?
```

Comment: okay.. - try first to not mix .then().catch()-chains with async wait blocks, as both basically do the same and you should use once concept not both. https://javascript.info/promise-chaining - if it does not work still post again

Answer (score 0):

Some issues here:

1. [Setting state does not happen immediately.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)  See the link for more on why your state would log an old value right after being set.
2. You're not returning anything from your chained calls - the `.finally` would have to return something for the variable to get populated.
3. Try to avoid mixing `await` and `.then`.  It can be harder to read and reason about.

If all you need `code` for is making the 2nd API call, you don't need to store it in state; it can stay inside your useEffect function.  Ex:

```js
  const dateTime = new Date().toJSON();
  const [gameData, setGameData] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
      try {
        // removed .then/.catch blocks - if there's an error,
        // it will be caught by the outer try/catch.  This ensures
        // firstResponse will be populated when the next call is made,
        // and setGameDate won't be called if there's an error there
        const firstResponse = await axios
          .post(apiUrl + "/games", {
            game: {
              name: dateTime,
            },
          });
        const thirdResponse = await axios
          .get(apiUrl + "/games/" + firstResponse.data.code);
        const newData = JSON.stringify(thirdResponse.data);
        setGameData(newData);
        console.log("Get is done");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      }
    };
    asyncFunction();
  }, []);
```