# Function json() returns an Object with an array inside, I want an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Fetch to get data from a json server and save it in the `connection` constant. After getting the data, I use `connection.json()` to transform the json into a javascript object. But I can't map this object, because it is an Object with an array inside. I would like to turn it into an array of objects. How should I proceed?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    list();
  }, [ ]);

  async function list(){
    try{
      const connection = await fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/priscilasilvaalves/priscilasilvaalves.github.io/db");
      const list = await connection.json();
      setItems(list);
      console.log(items); // Returns an Object with an array inside
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Firstly where you `console.log(items)` that **will not** be the value you just passed to`setItems` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558200/3001761). But secondly if you want to access the property of an object you do it the same way here as anywhere else - use dot `foo.bar` or bracket `foo["bar"]` notation.

Comment: Whats the model you are getting the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response contains the node lista. If you access it directly, you will get the desired result.

```js
async function list(){
  try{
    const connection = await fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/priscilasilvaalves/priscilasilvaalves.github.io/db");
    const list = await connection.json();
    setItems(list.lista); // Access the 'lista' property directly
    console.log(items);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to render the array of objects,
you can use something like this,

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  async function list() {
    try {
      const connection = await fetch(
        'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/priscilasilvaalves/priscilasilvaalves.github.io/db'
      );
      const list = await connection.json();
      setItems(list.lista);
      console.log(list.lista); // used this to get access of the array
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

return (
      {item.map((i) => (
        <span>
          <div>{i.id}</div>
          <div>{i.nome}</div>
        </span>
      ))}
)
```

Comment: setItems(list.lista) resolve the problem