# React useState didn't immediately update with value from input when onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i am new in React, i have a begginer question I can't solved it.

I have a simple Input and Button to get data from API.

```
// function to handleChange

const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
const [getCityData, setGetCityData] = useState('');
const [cityData, setCityData] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchQuery(e.target.value)
}


// function to handle button get City from API

const handleClick = () => {
    if (searchQuery !== "") {
        try {
            setGetCityData(searchQuery);
            fetchCity();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}


// function to get data from API

const fetchCity = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(url)
        console.log(res.data);
        setCityData(res.data);
        console.log(cityData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I press the button after fill the input, it always log with empty array first.
First line is data from API, the second line is log from function
[image: console log]

and when fill the input with another City, it display the previous data.
I think when we fetch the city it did not update the latest value.

How we fix this? or how we 'delay' the request API after useState is fill with the latest value.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
const [cityData, setCityData] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (e) => {
setSearchQuery(e.target.value)
}


// function to handle button get City from API

const handleClick = () => {
    if (searchQuery !== "") {
            fetchCity(searchQuery);
    }
}


// function to get data from API

const fetchCity = async (query) => {
    try {
        // baseUrl is nothing but the url without query eg: https://something.com/?query=
        const url = baseUrl+query
        console.log(url);
        const res = await axios.get(url)
        console.log(res.data);
        setCityData(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

i don't know how you are generating the url on axios get method and passing the search query in the request, it seems like you are passing along with url.
Try this method by passing query as a param to the fetchCity function and add it with the baseurl

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I am sorry I didn't put my whole code.
Yes, I have already the url is baseUrl with query beforehand.

Comment: ok.. but i couldn’t find any query details you are send on api

Comment: I can get the data from the API, but the problem is the useState it didn't immediately update with the new data, always the previous one.